# Xen kernel will not boot after upgrade to Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: xen, ubuntu-10.04, lvm

We upgraded our Ubuntu with Xen to 10.04 after the upgrade it will boot into the regular ubuntu, however it will not boot into the Xen (3.3) kernel.

Our output :

[image: Screen output]

What we tried :

- increase rootdelay on the vmlinuz line in grub
- rootwait

Result :

none, it always falls back to a shell that doesn't respond to anything.

Has anyone come across this error ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/199444/new-install-ubuntu-10-10-server-wont-boot-ls-dev-disk-by-uuid-generates-bus

Comment: he is running ubuntu not Xen, we already looked at that solution too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up booting ubuntu and migrating the images to KVM

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt find the root Filesystem because the UUID of the disc is wrong

You have two options:

1.) edit the root part directly in the bootloader grub. Replace UUID=123123..... with the right rootfs /dev/sdaX.
Once the system boots run update-grub

2a.) boot a Rescuesystem like grml or SystemRescueCd. If your System is 64bit boot 64bit kernel!
- mount the rootfs probably /dev/sda1 to /mnt
- then run the following commands to update grub

```
bash
chroot /mnt  update-grub
```

2b.) If 2 fails you can reinstall grub with this:
- mount the rootfs probably /dev/sda1 to /mnt, then:

```
bash
mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/dev 
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt  grub-install /dev/sda
```

I hope this helps
Tim